# R ggplot too many labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset:

```
x timw                y     class
1 2010-04-01 00:00:00 843.2 normal
2 2010-04-01 00:01:00 846.3 normal
3 2010-04-01 00:02:00 838.6 normal
4 2010-04-01 00:03:00 839.9 normal
5 2010-04-01 00:04:00 841.0 normal
6 2010-04-01 00:05:00 843.3 normal
7 2010-04-01 00:06:00 844.2 normal
8 2010-04-01 00:07:00 844.6 normal
9 2010-04-01 00:08:00 840.0 normal
10 2010-04-01 00:09:00 842.2 normal
```

I use ggplot in order to view data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(aes(color=factor(class)))+
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("normal" = "green","early warning" = "orange","changepoint" = "red"))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", 
                                 size=14, angle=90)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=as.character(df$time))
```

The problem is that there is printed one timestamp foreach point, and if I increase the dataset size, the timestamps ovaelaps.

[image: 100 timestamps picture]

I tried to use `breaks` prameters in `scale_x_discrete` but it does not display any timestamp:

```
indexes<-c(1,10,15)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(aes(color=factor(class)))+
scale_colour_manual(
values = c("normal" = "green","early warning" = "orange","changepoint" = "red"))+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", 
                             size=14, angle=90)) +
scale_x_discrete(breaks=indexes limits=as.character(df$time))
```

[image: 0 timestamps picture]

Comment: Try to convert your timestamps to a date with `as.Date`. `ggplot` should then be able to display the labels more nicely automatically.

Comment: @coffeinjunky I think `strptime` to convert to a date-time format is better suited in this case

Comment: Good point! `as.Date` might not work indeed. The important point is though to tell `ggplot` the time variable is not a character, but a time variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a continuous or datetime variable, `scale_x_discrete` is not the correct scale to use. As the name already implies, you can only use that for discrete (= factor or grouping) variables.

Therefore, you have to make sure that you `timw` variable is in the correct date-time format first. You can do this with `strptime`:

```
mydf$timw <- strptime(mydf$timw, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
```

When you plot, you can set the breaks and the formatting of the labels with `scale_x_datetime`, an example:

```
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = timw, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '1 mins', date_labels = '%H:%M') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14)
```

which gives:

[image]

---

Used data:

```
mydf <- structure(list(x = 1:10, 
                       timw = c("2010-04-01 00:00:00", "2010-04-01 00:01:00", "2010-04-01 00:02:00", "2010-04-01 00:03:00",
                                "2010-04-01 00:04:00", "2010-04-01 00:05:00", "2010-04-01 00:06:00", "2010-04-01 00:07:00", 
                                "2010-04-01 00:08:00", "2010-04-01 00:09:00"), 
                       y = c(843.2, 846.3, 838.6, 839.9, 841, 843.3, 844.2, 844.6, 840, 842.2), 
                       class = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "normal", class = "factor")), 
                  .Names = c("x", "timw", "y", "class"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```